# NSStatusItem tooltip – change delay

Tags: macos, tooltip, delay, nsstatusitem

I have a `NSStatusItem` to which I've added a tooltip using the `setToolTip:` method.

Everything works, except that the delay before showing the tooltip seems to be about 3 seconds, which is not ideal for my application.

Is there a way to change the delay before the tooltip is shown? Ideally, I'd like the delay to be 0 (i.e., the tooltip is immediately displayed when the user hovers over the icon).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1]
                                          forKey: @"NSInitialToolTipDelay"];
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with `0`, but it works fine with `1`. One question though, does this change the setting for the entire system or just my app (which is what I want)?

Comment: Should be just for your app... and should be very easy to confirm that as well :)

Comment: I'd like to know how to set the fade-out time to make the tooltips last longer.